# Destructuring and property shorthand error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am new to node, and I was working with destructuring. I wanted to get the body property from the response of an weather-api and destructure it. The code is working fine when I am connected with internet but when I disconnect the internet the code crash and throws the error.

> Here is the code I have written

````
```const request = require('request')

const geocode = (address, callback)=>{
    const url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" +encodeURIComponent(address)+ ".json?access_token=theKeyHere"

    request({url, json: true}, (error, {body})=>{
        if(error){
            callback('Uh! Oh, Unable to connect with location service', undefined )
        } else if (body.features.length ===0 || body.message){
            callback(`Uh! Oh, Can't find location. Try another search`, undefined)
        } else {
            callback(undefined, {
                latitude: body.features[0].center[1],
                longitude: body.features[0].center[0],
                location_Name: body.features[0].place_name
            })
        }
    })
}     ```
````

The error which I am getting

```
    request({url, json: true}, (error, {body={}})=>{
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at Request._callback (F:\nodejs\weatherApp\utils\geocode.js:6:41)
    at self.callback (F:\nodejs\weatherApp\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (F:\nodejs\weatherApp\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when there's an error, you're still trying to destructure the data:

```
request({url, json: true}, (error, {body={}})=>{
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
```

But in the error case, the data hasn't arrived, you've gotten `undefined` instead. You can't destructure `undefined` or `null`.

You have two options:

1. Use a plain parameter, and then destructure once you know you don't have an error:

   ```
    request({url, json: true}, (error, response)=>{
        if (error) {
            // ...
            return;
        }
        const {body = {}} = response;
        // ...
    });
   ```
2. Provide a default for the parameter as a whole, not just `body`:

   ```
    request({url, json: true}, (error, {body={}} = {})=>{
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
        // ...
    });
   ```

   That way, if you're passed `undefined`, you'll destructure `{}` instead. And since you're already defaulting `body` if it doesn't exist on the object, that default will kick in.

Comment: i knew you were probably answering this, so i posted a short answer about what the problem is first, then added how to fix it (so I can be first)! ;p

Answer (score 0):

the issue is, when you're not connected to the internet, or you dont get the expected response structure, the second argument of that function is `undefined`. so you're essentially trying to do this:

`undefined.body` which, of course, is wrong

you can do 2 things to fix it:

```
// - this will guarantee that the second argument will always default to 
//   an empty object. this way, you will not get an error
(error, { body={} } = {}) => {
```

or

```
(error, response) => {
  let body = {};
  if (response) body = response.body || {};
}
```